# Bug in using jQuery to find out if user scrolled to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very complicated situation here. I might be just blind to my own error. I have this code here:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll 
    if($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        alert('Scrolled to Page Bottom');
        }
```

Instead of alerting me when user scrolls to the bottom of the page, it alerts me when user scrolls to the top of the page.. I have looked at a very similar code here, but I still can't make this work.

Here is the whole script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
            var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
            var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)

            $('#results').load("autoload_process.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;}); //load first group

            $(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll

                if($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
                {
                    alert('Scrolled to Page Bottom');
                    if(track_load < total_groups && loading==false) //there's more data to load
                    {
                        loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
                        $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

                        //load data from the server using a HTTP POST request
                        $.post('autoload_process.php',{'group_no': track_load}, function(data){

                            $("#results").append(data); //append received data into the element

                            //hide loading image
                            $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                            track_load++; //loaded group increment
                            loading = false; 

                        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

                            alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                            $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
                            loading = false;

                        });

                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you getting anything in your console? It looks like you are missing some of your code because the function and scroll call aren't closed. I put what you did provide into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sagsw5w/) and it worked fine.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter, but what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I put your whole script into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/med0b3ts/1/) again and it still works.

Comment: This will probably be considered spam, but please take a look at [My example](http://goo.gl/m1glcv), as I am now very confused. I have tested it in multiple browsers and I am getting the same effect..

Comment: It seems like the script itself is working fine, but there is something going on with your HTML and styling that could be causing the issue. I noticed when you view source you didn't close your body and html tags. Look into little things like that to make sure you didn't miss anything

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, buddy! I have never been so confused. I checked all my tags and it all seems to be fine. I have closed my HTML and BODY tags and the problem is still there. I bet it will be something ridiculously simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working, I couldn't find problems on it. And I tested it in a JSFiddle and it's working, see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/54ta3hug/

```
$(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll 
    if($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        alert('Scrolled to Page Bottom');
        }
    });
```

By looking at you example at http://writinger.com/ , with some debugging I found out that for some reason $(window).height() is returning the same value as $(document).height() in your page. That's why it shows when scrolling to the top, when $(document).scrollTop() is 0.

But of course it's clear that in your example, the document is bigger, since there is a scroll bar.
I believe it's returning a wrong value for $(window).height() because your HTML document is not well formatted. Also, probably it does not have DOCTYPE declaration. which means that it’s not a valid HTML. BEcause of it, JQuery is not able to calculate window height / document height in a correct way if you don't specify doctype.

Fix your HTML and also add DOCTYPE declaration to it. After it, it should work.

Comment: I've done some changes to my answer after looking at the example you provided. Take a look at it.